# aws-cpp-sdk : How to IoT publish using MQTT over Web Socket (in c++)

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, websocket, mqtt, iot

I did a lot of research (here and on github) to find out how Iot Data Plane class works.

I wonder how I could publish data on a topic with the c++ sdk and use of port 443. I would like to establish my connection, and have the connection alive until I close it.

In brief, I need help to use the cpp sdk to send MQTT over Web Socket, on Linux.

Does anyone can help?

```
 Aws::SDKOptions options;
 options.loggingOptions.logLevel = Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Info;
 Aws::InitAPI(options);

 Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials credentials;
 credentials.SetAWSAccessKeyId("a valid key id generated in Aws IAM");
 credentials.SetAWSSecretKey("a valid secret key generated in Aws IAM");

 Aws::IoTDataPlane::IoTDataPlaneClient client(credentials);
 Aws::IoTDataPlane::Model::PublishRequest request;
 std::shared_ptr<Aws::StringStream> stream = std::make_shared<Aws::StringStream>("Something to publish.");

 request.SetBody(stream);
 request.SetTopic("MyTopic");

 Aws::IoTDataPlane::Model::PublishOutcome outcome(client.Publish(request));
 if(outcome.IsSuccess())
 {
    printf("Success");
 }
 else
 {
    printf("%s", outcome.GetError().GetMessage().c_str());
 }
 Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
```

Comment: Can you show some code you've written or some links that you have searched for ? It'll help others to help

Answer (score 0):

What I want to do is not yet possible, as answered by a software engineer of Aws on Git Hub.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/issues/594

> the c++ sdk does not support mqtt at the moment. We have plans to add this to an upcoming c99 sdk. We'll keep you posted. In the meantime, if you need to use mqtt you can use the iot sdk.